# Десериализация из коллекции. C#

Tags: c#

```
List<Person> parts = new List<Person>();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
        //Код десериализации ломает программу
        if (File.Exists("person.xml")){

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            List<Person> newParts = (List<Person>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
            Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");}
        }while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите команду:");
            string com = Console.ReadLine();
            if (com.ToLower() == "exit")
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    xs.Serialize(fs, parts);
                   // Console.WriteLine("Объект сериализован");
                }
                return;
            }
            if (com.ToLower() == "add")
            {
                 string name;
                 Console.WriteLine("Name?");
                 name = Console.ReadLine();
                 Person p = new Person(name);
                 parts.Add(p);
            }
            if (com.ToLower() != "add")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Доступные команды:");
                Console.WriteLine("\tadd создать запись сотрудника");
                Console.WriteLine("\texit Выйти и сохранить данные");
                Console.ReadKey();
                continue;
            }

       }

     }
}  
  [Serializable]
   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public Person()
       { }
       public Person(string name)
       {
           Name = name;
       }
   }
}
```

Здравствуйте!Делаю базу данных. Меню консольное. При команде "add" добавляю сотрудника(name)  в коллецию parts. При команде "exit" сериализую в формате xml
в файл person.xml. Все проходит отлично. Но когда вставляю код,чтоб при запуске была проверка этого файла и его десериализация у меня ломается программа. В чем может причина?

Comment: Если вы выкинете из кода взаимодействие с пользователем, его будет проще понять. [mcve]

Comment: Текст исключения тоже лишним не будет.

Comment: "у меня ломается программа" - что есть это? Никогда (Вы слышите? Никогда!) не указывайте, какую ошибку Вы получаете. Мы настолько талантливы и прозорливы, что догадаемся сами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверяйте наличие файла перед десериализацией:

```
  if (File.Exists("person.xml"))
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
```

Comment: Добавил и проверку. Все равно exeption

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев если пустой файл уже создан в папке с программой - его удалите. Вообще, цикл работы должен быть явно посложнее, но ваш основной вопрос был именно в этом.

Comment: Удалять нельзя его. Я должен загрузить этот список в newParts

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев тогда нужен текст исключения, потому что в таком виде у меня код уже работает.

Comment: У меня тоже заработал после удаления файла. Получается он поврежден был. Теперь десериализует верно.

Comment: Добавляю другую команду для выведения списка имен на экран. Нет свойства Name у parts. Подскажите как вывести?     if (com.ToLower() == "allsee")
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}", parts. );
                    continue;
                }

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newParts.Select(p => p.Name)));` например вот так в столбец. Надо будет ещё подключить `using System.Linq;`